# How to save articles I'm getting from rss to core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, rss

I have a project where I get rss feed from some website ad i'm parsing it and presenting it in a table view.

right now every time I log in to the app I pull the articles from the internet, and I want to save the ones that was already loaded before in core data so I can 1. get the articles faster, 2. read articles offline.

This is my main view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FParser.h"


@class FWebViewController;


@interface FMainViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,FParserDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *_allEntries;
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    NSOperationQueue *_queue;
    NSArray *_feeds;
    FWebViewController *_webViewController;
    FParser *parser;
}
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *allEntries;
@property (retain) NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property (retain) NSArray *feeds;
@property (retain) FWebViewController *webViewController;


@end
```

and the .m:

```
#import "FMainViewController.h"
#import "FRSSEntry.h"
#import "FWebViewController.h"
#import "FTableViewCell.h"
#import "FCoreDataStack.h"
#import "Article.h"


@interface FMainViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultsController; 

@end

@implementation FMainViewController
@synthesize allEntries = _allEntries;
@synthesize feeds = _feeds;
@synthesize queue = _queue;
@synthesize webViewController = _webViewController;

-(id)init{

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"FMainViewController" bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
        parser = [[FParser alloc]init];
        parser.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.title = @"RSS FEED!";

}

#pragma mark - TableViewController DataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_allEntries count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"FTableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    FRSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setCellWithRSSEntry:entry];

    return cell;
}

// Replace tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath with the following
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (_webViewController == nil) {
        self.webViewController = [[FWebViewController alloc] init];
    }
    FRSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    FTableViewCell *tmpCell = (FTableViewCell *)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *tmpCellImage = [tmpCell getImage];

    [_webViewController setEntry:entry setCoverImage:tmpCellImage];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];

}

#pragma mark - FParserDelegate

-(void)doneParsingEntries:(NSMutableArray *)entries{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        for (FRSSEntry *entry in entries) {

            int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                FRSSEntry *entry1 = (FRSSEntry *) a;
                FRSSEntry *entry2 = (FRSSEntry *) b;
                return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
            }];

            [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
            [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                               withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        }

    }];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    self.webViewController = nil;

}
@end
```

do you have a suggestion for me?

tnx

Comment: Would it not be best to use `NSFileManager` to organise a directory and save the documents to file. A CoreData database isn't best suited to text based documents/articles, rather it is suited to repetitive data. If you need to save metadata you can use `NSFileWrapper` or save `.plist` formatted metadata. The .plist files could be used to quickly populate a table and then you would only have to load the artivcles from the HD upon the user's request.